# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' but type is 'bytes'

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

So I'm trying to replace some chars in string but python doesn't recognize its type correctly. Any ideas why is that??

```py
...
print(type(word))
word.replace('0', 'O')
...
```

```
<class 'bytes'>
```

is printed but i get:

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

---

So I'm making some text-correction over recognized text from a bill. 
I have a recognized text in the self.text variable which has a `<str class>`.

```py
 def text_correction(self):
        '''
            Post processing, replace some characters.
        '''
        self.total = ""
        self.date = ""
        print(type(self.text))   #return <class 'str'> 

        lines = self.text.split('\n')
        new_string = ""

        for line in lines:

            line = line.encode("ascii")
            new_line = ""

            words = line.split()

            for word in words:

                type_of_word = self.get_type_of_word(word)
                print(type(word)) #return <class 'bytes'>
                if type_of_word == 0:
                    word.replace('0', 'O')
                    word.replace('l', 'I')
             ...
```

get_type_of_word function is just a check whether is upper/lower or digit a char is:

```py
 def get_type_of_word(self, word):
        '''
            Define type of word.
        '''
        type_of_word = []
        count =0
        type_of_word.append(sum(1 for c in word if chr(c).isupper()))
        type_of_word.append(sum(1 for c in word if chr(c).islower()))
        type_of_word.append(sum(1 for c in word if chr(c).isdigit()))
        type_of_word.append(len(word) - sum(type_of_word))

        if type_of_word[0] == type_of_word[2] and type_of_word[0] != 0:
            return 2
        else:
            return type_of_word.index(max(type_of_word))
```

Comment: Maybe `str` is the type of `'0'`. Try with `word.replace(b'0', b'O')`.

Comment: word variable is also printed out like b'foo'

Comment: `b"foo"` is a bytes object.

Answer (score 4):

The [`replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.replace) method, when used on a `bytes` object, requires `bytes` objects as arguments too.

So instead of:

```py
word.replace('0', 'O')
```

write:

```py
word.replace(b'0', b'O')
```

However, if you're text processing, I wonder why you work with `bytes` objects instead of `str` objects. Working directly on strings makes more sense then. So, make sure that `word` is of type `str` instead of `bytes` and then `word.replace('0', 'O')` would work as expected. To do this, your code only needs two modifications:

- remove the following statement: `line = line.encode("ascii")`
- in `get_type_of_word()` just use `c` instead of `chr(c)`

Also note that `word.replace('0', 'O')` has no effect, since it does not really change the word but returns a (modified) copy of it. So you should assign it to have any effect, e.g. `word = word.replace('0', 'O')`.